# iOS Xcode 12 _CodeSignature folder not created when generate SDK Framework having Cpp code or files

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, swift-framework

I'm trying to create SDK framework in xCode12. My code have the cpp file, Objective-c and .swift files

Now, when i try to generate the framework and i'm able to build the project and it's successfully build framework but the "_codesignature" folder is not generated so when i'm import this framework in other project it's gives import error.

If i remove .cpp and Objective-c files then i'm able to generate framework with "_codesignature" folder, and able to import the framework into other project successfully.

So can any please suggest why .cpp files not allow to create "_codesignature" folder when generating framework.

Comment: what is the error? could you provide the build log in both cases (with or without extra files?)